# using string array to dump hyperlink equation comes out as text

Tags: arrays, excel, hyperlink, vba

I'm using a string array to collect file paths and a hyperlink to that file. The code below is a simplified version of what I'm doing, but it seems to suffer the same problem. This sub outputs data into two columns. The first column is the file name, complete with path, the second is a hyperlink equation to allow the user to open that file.

```
  Sub string_dump()

  Dim i As Long
  Dim str() As String
  ReDim str(10, 1)

    For i = 0 To 10
      str(i, 0) = "C:\Users\Wegner\Documents\Programs\Document1.txt"
      str(i, 1) = "=hyperlink(rc[-1],""link"")"
    Next i

    Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(13, 2)) = str

  End Sub
```

The problem is that after the array is dumped in the worksheet cells the hyperlink equation is displayed in the cell like this:

=hyperlink(rc[-1],"link")

I want it to be the actual hyperlink. If you press F2 then Enter on any of the cells it becomes the hyperlink. Can someone tell me what I'm missing here? What's driving me nuts is that the code below does exactly what I want.

```
Sub equation_dump()

  Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(13, 2)) = "=hyperlink(rc[-1],""link"")"

End Sub
```

I have to get the string dump method working, in lieu of the above method. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

leave `str` as a `variant`

```
Sub string_dump()

Dim i As Long
Dim str()
ReDim str(10, 1)

For i = 0 To 10
   str(i, 0) = "C:\Users\Wegner\Documents\Programs\Document1.txt"
   str(i, 1) = "=hyperlink(rc[-1],""link"")"
Next i

Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(13, 2)).FormulaR1C1 = str

End Sub
```